# Pagination Link Not Clickable with JQuery

Tags: jquery, razor, pagination

I have the following code on the Razor page and the JS function is supposed to be called when the link is clicked, but nothing happened. It seems disabled. Could anyone help with this? Below is the code:

Code on Razor page:

```
                @for(var pge = Model.StartPage; pge <= Model.EndPage; pge++)
                {
                        <li class="page-item @(pge == Model.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                            <a id="@("#plink" + pge)" class="rpt_btn_lnk page-link pglink"
                               data-action="@ViewData["ActionName"]"
                               data-pg="@pge"
                               data-pageSize="@ViewData["PageSize"]"
                               data-category="@ViewData["CategoryId"]"
                               data-categoryAction="@ViewData["CategoryAction"]"
                               data-currentSearchFilter="@TempData["CurrentSearchFilter"]">
                                @pge
                            </a>
                        </li>
                }
```

JQuery:

```
                $(function () {
                    $(".rpt_btn_lnk").click(function () {
                        var pageSize = $(this).attr('data-pageSize');
                        var pg = $(this).attr('data-pg');
                        var category = $(this).attr('data-category');
                        var categoryAction = $(this).attr('data-categoryAction');
                        var currentSearchFilter = $(this).attr('data-currentSearchFilter');
                        var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
                        $("#partialRptList").load("/Report/" + action + "?id=" + id + "&pg=" + pg + "&category=" + category + "&categoryAction=" + categoryAction
                            + "&currentSearchFilter=" + currentSearchFilter + "&pageSize=" + pageSize);
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if the pagination is DOM loaded?

Try replacing `$(".rpt_btn_lnk").click(function () {` with `$(document).on('click', '.rpt_btn_lnk', function(){`

Comment: I appreciate your help. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried your code and the original code after a break, and both of them work fine. I'm not sure why it didn't work initially.